# C# Build Expression tree based on Conditional operator to use with MongoDB filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, lambda, expression-trees

I am building an expression tree based on the conditional operator but I am unable to get the required filter working with MongoDb function.

Here is my function

```
 public Task<long> GetUserCountAsync(string tenantId, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            ThrowIfDisposed();

            Expression<Func<TUser, bool>> filter = t => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tenantId) ? t.TenantId != null : t.TenantId == tenantId;
            return await mongoCollection.CountDocumentsAsync(filter);
        }
```

when I run the above code I received the following error

[image]

**My question is how to build an expression tree using a conditional operator?**

```
 Expression<Func<TUser, bool>> filter = t => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tenantId) ? t.TenantId != null : t.TenantId == tenantId;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the db does not support the expression you are trying to build.

Change the approach. Do not include the conditional in the expression itself

```
//...

Expression<Func<TUser, bool>> filter = t => t.TenantId == tenantId;

if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tenantId))
    filter = t => t.TenantId != null;
    
//...
```

Comment: your first proposed code is not working. I am having an error that says "Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'lambda expression' and 'lambda expression" although second one is working. Any reason why?

Comment: In that case I'll remove it and go with the more verbose one